# Running Jenkins in Docker - Exits immediately

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a Jenkins server with docker.

I've built the image, and trying to run it with this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 62a4e44bf4bf
```

The 62a4e44bf4bf is the docker image ID

Whenever I run this command, it shuts down immediately.

I've tried with this command:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 62a4e44bf4bf
```

Which will keep the image running, but I can't seem to access the jenkins from my browser with this ip: localhost:8080

## DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Oracle Java7 install
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer

#Jenkins install
RUN wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN sudo echo "deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/" >>     /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --force-yes -y jenkins

#Zip support install
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install zip

#Unzip hang.zip
#RUN cp /shared/hang.zip /var/lib/jenkins
#RUN unzip -o /var/jenkins/hang.zip -d /var/lib/jenkins/

#Restart jenkins server
RUN service jenkins start

EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 4):

@Detilium There is no CMD or ENTRYPOINT in your `Dockerfile`, that's why it automatically exits, because your container has nothing to run. According to your own answer, you probably made it work by using `exec` or running bash and starting it manually, I guess ?

There something wrong with you `Dockerfile` though. Docker container have to run a process as `pid 1` (inside the container) and it has to run in foreground (no daemon).

More over, images reperesent filesystems, not state. if you start a process in a step of your image building (in the `Dockerfile`), the fact it's running will not be /persisted/, so it won't be started again when you run a container based on this image. The default command that will be runned by docker when starting the container is definde with `CMD`.

```
RUN service jenkins start
```

The line above does not work. It will start jenkins at this step of the build and make a layer (that might be empty even). But the next layer that will be created (another step or the actual `docker run`) will not have the jenkins service/process running.

For /inspiration/ for a Jenkins `Dockerfile`, you could look at https://github.com/aespinosa/docker-jenkins/blob/master/Dockerfile . Note the `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]` could also be 
`CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]`.

I encourage you to read the following documentation for more comprehension about docker : https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/, https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/ and https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible permissions on your jenkins directory are a problem when jenkins container will not stay running. I did 'docker pull jenkins' and was surprised to find it would not run. https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

To debug your error then start the image using the -i (interactive flag). (use 'docker ps -a |grep jenkins' if you don't know your ID)

```
docker start 62a4e44bf4bf -i
```

I saw an error like this:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

So I checked /var/jenkins_home ownership and permissions.
I saw that the $PWD/jenkins dir had been created with root:root 700 permission. I adjusted (Sledgehammer approach): 'sudo chmod 777 $PWD/jenkins'. Problem solved. Container ran ok and ran the install of jenkins into that directory.

I am running jenkins container like this: (PWD=/home/myuser so /var/jenkins_home in container is actually $PWD/jenkins on docker server)

```
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:z -t jenkins
```

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 $PWD/jenkins`
`sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:z -t jenkins/jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but in my case it was lack of memory that caused the shutdown. I'm running docker on Docker Desktop on a mac. Allocating more memory to Docker Desktop solved the issue. Maybe this can help someone.