# Docker ; Wrong volume permissions?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I pulled a Jenkins official image in docker and want to start the jenkins container but It seems I have a permission problem which I really did not understant despite I find the same issue in the net but they doesn't helped me to fix my issue.
I want to start the jenkins container with this command `docker compose up -d` but I got this issue:

```
Creating jenkins_Container ... done
Attaching to jenkins_Container
jenkins_Container | touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
jenkins_Container | Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
jenkins_Container exited with code 1
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins_Container
    image: docker.io/jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - '$PWD/jenkins_Home:/var/jenkins_home'
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

any suggestion is appreciated...

Regards

Comment: Did you change the ownership of jenkins home?

Comment: yes with this command: sudo chown -R 1000:1000 jenkins_Home

Answer (score 0):

after some research this solved my problem by running this command :

```
 docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins_Home:/var/jenkins_home:z -t docker.io/jenkins/jenkins
```

got it from [Running Jenkins in Docker - Exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026581/running-jenkins-in-docker-exits-immediately)